# how to use MBProgressHUD to pause the screen when the loading animating

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, mbprogresshud

I have a problem.
I use MBProgressHUD in my tableviewcontroller.
I want that the MBProgressHUD loading animating then user can't touch anything and wait to get server data to show on the tableview.
I want to pause screen until hud hideAnimated.

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.listTableView animated:YES];
hud.label.text = @"Loading";
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self getInfo:nil];
});
hud.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[hud hideAnimated:YES afterDelay:2];
```

Comment: Do you have a callback for the request? You should do `[hud hideAnimated:YES]` there.

Comment: Where do you want to pause???

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `[hud hideAnimated:YES afterDelay:2]` in this case.  There is no point in `dispatch_after` either.

The thing is that your request may finish really quick (like 0.1 sec) and the hud will be still shown for another 1.9 sec. Or it may stay pending for a really long time, like 30 seconds or whatever timeout you set, so your code will hide the hud when it should actually be shown.

What you should do is to call completion blocks (or delegate methods) when the request is finished (successfully or not).

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.label.text = @"Loading";
[self getInfoWithSuccess:^{
    [hud hideAnimated:YES];
    //your code here        
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    [hud hideAnimated:YES];
    //show error message if needed
}];
```

Request method itself:

```
- (void) getInfoWithSuccess: (void(^)()) success failure: (void(^)(NSError *)) failure {
    //do async request here and call success or failure block when it's finished
}
```